# Why the .replace function is not working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to erase "." from a DataFrame column using the replace function but i have no idea why is not working. The currently column looks like:

```
Time
5:00 PM
4:00AM
3:30 P.M
2:00 .P.M
```

What i want is to change that column to a DataTime Hour type , but i think that i need to clean it first. So, in order to do that i want to erase the "." but when i use:

```
df.Time=df.Time.replace({'.':''})
```

still does not work. How can i do it?

Comment: The `replace` method of a series looks for a replaces entries of the series, rather than substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
print(df.Time.str.replace('.','', regex=True))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can u explain me the difference?

Comment: You are using a dictionary, which is used to remap data in column. It replaces if there is a full match as @ProfessorPantsless suggested. Refer this link for further info. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-dictionary-to-remap-values-in-pandas-dataframe-columns/amp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.Time=df.Time.apply(lambda x: x.replace('.',''))
```